# Is posible represent a matrix $A$ like $A=\lambda U$ where $U$ is a unitary matrix and $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, unitary-matrices

Determine if is possible to represent the matriz $$\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
i & 0 & 2\\
2i & 0 & -1\\
0 & -(1+2i) & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}$$
like $A=\lambda U$ where $U \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ is an unitary matrix and $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. Is possible have $\overline{\lambda}=\lambda$?

I took a eigenvector $v$ of $A$ associated to the eigenvalue $c$, so  $Av=cv$.
Since se want that $ A= \lambda U$ so $cv= \lambda U v$. 
Then $ Uv = \frac{c}{\lambda}v$ for $|| \lambda || \neq 0$, therefore $U$ and $A$ have the same eigenvectors.

Comment: Which are your tries to solve it?

Comment: What's $A\overline A^t$?

Comment: @PabloHerrera I edit de post and add it

Comment: Check Angina's anwers the columns of $A$ should be orthogonal, so $A$ is an orthogonal matrix and if you normalize the columns then you will get a unitary matrix.